# Como redimensionar automaticamente div's com imagem e descrição

Tags: java, html, css, imagem, div

Tenho um projeto no qual tenho produtos com imagem, descrição e preço, quero deixar as div's redimensionáveis de forma automática de acordo com a descrição e imagem.
Também quero um valor estático que não ultrapasse e desalinhe as div's, é possível?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: java ou javascript?

Comment: linguagem java para web

Comment: Já tentou usar bootstrap ou não tem intenção? http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).